# Xvfb in Python virtual environment

Tags: python, gtk, xvfb

I have some code that uses `gtk` so unless there is an active `DISPLAY`, the code raises an `RuntimeError: could not open display`… This happens when I run `tox`.

Is there a way to run a `Xvfb` server from within tox?

I did try adding

```
/usr/bin/Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1280x1024x24 &
```

to the commands section but got an `InvocationError` due to the `&`. Without it, the command never returns and thus blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `xvfb-run` like so:

```
xvfb-run --auto-display tox -v --recreate
```

This is easily done in Jenkins Pipefiles…

Comment: You might need to run it with "-a" if xvfb-run fails to start: `xvfb-run -a tox {command}`

Comment: @NoamManos From the help, `-a` is deprecated, use `--auto-display` instead.